# If $n\equiv 4 \pmod 9$ then $n$ cannot be written as sum of three cubes?

Tags: number-theory, congruences

> Show that if $n\equiv 4 \pmod 9$ then $n$ cannot be written as sum of three cubes.

This might be a silly question but I really don't see it? The thing I ended up was: let $n=a^3 + b^3 + c^3$, then we'll end up with $[a]^3+[b]^3+[c]^3=[4]$ in $Z_9$. I found several webpages and apparently this is quite "obvious".

Comment: Using the command $\tt{\backslash}\tt{pmod}$ gives good results for parenthesis modulo notation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT** Note that $m^3 \equiv 0, \pm1 \pmod9$.

Comment: Aha, I see it now. This result is not "obvious" to me though.. :(

Comment: By the way how would you prove this statement? Just simply go through $0^3$ to $9^3$?

Comment: A more rigorous explanation and proof is here : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1523147/1311