# Find $x, y$, and $z$ such that $x^3+y^3+z^3=k$, for each $k$ from $1$ to $100.$

Tags: diophantine-equations

It’s called a Diophantine Equation, and it’s sometimes known as the “summing of three cubes”.

> A Diophantine equation is a polynomial equation, usually in two or
> more unknowns, such that only the integer solutions are sought or
> studied (an integer solution is such that all the unknowns take
> integer values).

It seems easy for $x^3+y^3+z^3=8$.
$x=1$, $y=-1$ and $z=2.$

But what for higher values of $k$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sums_of_three_cubes

Comment: For $k=42$ , the problem turned out to be extremely difficult, but a solution was recently found. Now we know for all $k$ upto $100$ a solution or we know that none exists.

Comment: [The sum of three cubes](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1523130/318073)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using positive integers only for $x,y,z$ there are no solutions for $k<3$ but here are $3\le k \le 100$. The use of non-positive integers follows.

```
 (x,y,z,k)
 (1,1,1,3)
 (1,1,2,10)
 (1,2,2,17)
 (2,2,2,24)
 (1,1,3,29)
 (1,2,3,36)
 (2,2,3,43)
 (1,3,3,55)
 (2,3,3,62)
 (1,1,4,66)
 (1,2,4,73)
 (2,2,4,80)
 (3,3,3,81)
 (1,3,4,92)
 (2,3,4,99)
```

It appears that at least one of x,y,z must be positive if k is positive.

```
 (x,y,z,k)
 (-100,1,100,1)
 (-99,1,99,1)
 (-98,1,98,1)
 (-97,1,97,1)
 (-96,1,96,1)
 (-95,1,95,1)
 (-94,1,94,1)
 (-93,1,93,1)
 (-92,1,92,1)
 (-91,1,91,1)
 (-90,1,90,1)
 (-89,1,89,1)
 (-88,1,88,1)
 (-87,1,87,1)
 (-86,1,86,1)
 (-85,1,85,1)
 (-84,1,84,1)
 (-83,1,83,1)
 (-82,1,82,1)
 (-81,1,81,1)
 (-80,1,80,1)
 (-79,1,79,1)
 (-78,1,78,1)
 (-77,1,77,1)
 (-76,1,76,1)
 (-75,1,75,1)
 (-74,1,74,1)
 (-73,1,73,1)
 (-72,1,72,1)
 (-71,1,71,1)
 (-70,1,70,1)
 (-69,1,69,1)
 (-68,1,68,1)
 (-67,1,67,1)
 (-66,1,66,1)
 (-65,1,65,1)
 (-64,1,64,1)
 (-63,1,63,1)
 (-62,1,62,1)
 (-61,1,61,1)
 (-60,1,60,1)
 (-59,1,59,1)
 (-58,1,58,1)
 (-57,1,57,1)
 (-56,1,56,1)
 (-55,1,55,1)
 (-54,1,54,1)
 (-53,1,53,1)
 (-52,1,52,1)
 (-51,1,51,1)
 (-50,1,50,1)
 (-49,1,49,1)
 (-48,1,48,1)
 (-47,1,47,1)
 (-46,1,46,1)
 (-45,1,45,1)
 (-44,1,44,1)
 (-43,1,43,1)
 (-42,1,42,1)
 (-41,1,41,1)
 (-40,1,40,1)
 (-39,1,39,1)
 (-38,1,38,1)
 (-37,1,37,1)
 (-36,1,36,1)
 (-35,1,35,1)
 (-34,1,34,1)
 (-33,1,33,1)
 (-32,1,32,1)
 (-31,1,31,1)
 (-30,1,30,1)
 (-29,1,29,1)
 (-28,1,28,1)
 (-27,1,27,1)
 (-26,1,26,1)
 (-25,1,25,1)
 (-24,1,24,1)
 (-23,1,23,1)
 (-22,1,22,1)
 (-21,1,21,1)
 (-20,1,20,1)
 (-19,1,19,1)
 (-18,1,18,1)
 (-17,1,17,1)
 (-16,1,16,1)
 (-15,1,15,1)
 (-14,1,14,1)
 (-13,1,13,1)
 (-12,1,12,1)
 (-12,9,10,1)
 (-11,1,11,1)
 (-10,1,10,1)
 (-9,1,9,1)
 (-8,-6,9,1)
 (-8,1,8,1)
 (-7,1,7,1)
 (-6,1,6,1)
 (-5,1,5,1)
 (-4,1,4,1)
 (-3,1,3,1)
 (-2,1,2,1)
 (-1,1,1,1)
 (0,0,1,1)
 (-47,-24,49,2)
 (-6,-5,7,2)
 (0,1,1,2)
 (-5,4,4,3)
 (1,1,1,3)
 (-58,-43,65,6)
 (-1,-1,2,6)
 (-1,0,2,7)
 (-100,2,100,8)
 (-99,2,99,8)
 (-98,2,98,8)
 (-97,2,97,8)
 (-96,2,96,8)
 (-95,2,95,8)
 (-94,2,94,8)
 (-93,2,93,8)
 (-92,2,92,8)
 (-91,2,91,8)
 (-90,2,90,8)
 (-89,2,89,8)
 (-89,41,86,8)
 (-88,2,88,8)
 (-87,2,87,8)
 (-86,2,86,8)
 (-85,2,85,8)
 (-84,2,84,8)
 (-83,2,83,8)
 (-82,2,82,8)
 (-81,2,81,8)
 (-80,2,80,8)
 (-79,2,79,8)
 (-78,2,78,8)
 (-77,2,77,8)
 (-76,2,76,8)
 (-75,2,75,8)
 (-74,2,74,8)
 (-73,2,73,8)
 (-72,2,72,8)
 (-71,2,71,8)
 (-70,2,70,8)
 (-69,2,69,8)
 (-68,2,68,8)
 (-67,2,67,8)
 (-66,2,66,8)
 (-65,2,65,8)
 (-64,2,64,8)
 (-63,2,63,8)
 (-62,2,62,8)
 (-61,2,61,8)
 (-60,2,60,8)
 (-59,2,59,8)
 (-58,2,58,8)
 (-57,2,57,8)
 (-56,2,56,8)
 (-55,2,55,8)
 (-54,2,54,8)
 (-53,2,53,8)
 (-52,2,52,8)
 (-51,2,51,8)
 (-50,2,50,8)
 (-49,2,49,8)
 (-48,2,48,8)
 (-47,2,47,8)
 (-46,2,46,8)
 (-45,2,45,8)
 (-44,2,44,8)
 (-43,2,43,8)
 (-42,2,42,8)
 (-41,2,41,8)
 (-40,-17,41,8)
 (-40,2,40,8)
 (-39,2,39,8)
 (-38,2,38,8)
 (-37,2,37,8)
 (-36,2,36,8)
 (-35,2,35,8)
 (-34,2,34,8)
 (-34,15,33,8)
 (-33,2,33,8)
 (-32,2,32,8)
 (-31,2,31,8)
 (-30,2,30,8)
 (-29,2,29,8)
 (-28,2,28,8)
 (-27,2,27,8)
 (-26,2,26,8)
 (-25,2,25,8)
 (-24,2,24,8)
 (-24,18,20,8)
 (-23,2,23,8)
 (-22,2,22,8)
 (-21,2,21,8)
 (-20,2,20,8)
 (-19,2,19,8)
 (-18,2,18,8)
 (-17,2,17,8)
 (-16,-12,18,8)
 (-16,2,16,8)
 (-16,9,15,8)
 (-15,2,15,8)
 (-14,2,14,8)
 (-13,2,13,8)
 (-12,2,12,8)
 (-11,2,11,8)
 (-10,2,10,8)
 (-9,2,9,8)
 (-8,2,8,8)
 (-7,2,7,8)
 (-6,2,6,8)
 (-5,2,5,8)
 (-4,2,4,8)
 (-3,2,3,8)
 (-2,2,2,8)
 (-1,1,2,8)
 (0,0,2,8)
 (0,1,2,9)
 (-3,-3,4,10)
 (1,1,2,10)
 (-2,-2,3,11)
 (-11,7,10,12)
 (-46,23,44,15)
 (-1,2,2,15)
 (-94,-48,98,16)
 (-12,-10,14,16)
 (0,2,2,16)
 (-52,25,50,17)
 (1,2,2,17)
 (-2,-1,3,18)
 (-95,47,91,19)
 (-77,26,76,19)
 (-16,-14,19,19)
 (-2,0,3,19)
 (-56,21,55,20)
 (-2,1,3,20)
 (-86,28,85,21)
 (-14,-11,16,21)
 (-10,8,8,24)
 (2,2,2,24)
 (-1,-1,3,25)
 (-1,0,3,26)
 (-100,3,100,27)
 (-99,3,99,27)
 (-98,3,98,27)
 (-97,3,97,27)
 (-96,3,96,27)
 (-95,3,95,27)
 (-94,3,94,27)
 (-93,3,93,27)
 (-92,3,92,27)
 (-91,3,91,27)
 (-90,3,90,27)
 (-89,3,89,27)
 (-88,3,88,27)
 (-87,3,87,27)
 (-86,3,86,27)
 (-85,3,85,27)
 (-84,3,84,27)
 (-83,3,83,27)
 (-82,3,82,27)
 (-81,3,81,27)
 (-80,3,80,27)
 (-79,3,79,27)
 (-78,3,78,27)
 (-77,3,77,27)
 (-76,3,76,27)
 (-75,3,75,27)
 (-74,3,74,27)
 (-73,3,73,27)
 (-72,3,72,27)
 (-71,3,71,27)
 (-70,3,70,27)
 (-69,3,69,27)
 (-68,3,68,27)
 (-67,3,67,27)
 (-66,3,66,27)
 (-65,3,65,27)
 (-64,3,64,27)
 (-63,3,63,27)
 (-62,3,62,27)
 (-61,3,61,27)
 (-60,3,60,27)
 (-60,22,59,27)
 (-59,3,59,27)
 (-58,3,58,27)
 (-57,3,57,27)
 (-56,3,56,27)
 (-55,3,55,27)
 (-54,3,54,27)
 (-53,3,53,27)
 (-52,3,52,27)
 (-51,3,51,27)
 (-50,3,50,27)
 (-49,3,49,27)
 (-48,3,48,27)
 (-47,3,47,27)
 (-46,3,46,27)
 (-45,3,45,27)
 (-44,3,44,27)
 (-43,3,43,27)
 (-42,3,42,27)
 (-41,3,41,27)
 (-40,3,40,27)
 (-39,3,39,27)
 (-38,3,38,27)
 (-37,-36,46,27)
 (-37,3,37,27)
 (-36,3,36,27)
 (-36,27,30,27)
 (-35,3,35,27)
 (-34,3,34,27)
 (-33,3,33,27)
 (-32,3,32,27)
 (-31,3,31,27)
 (-30,3,30,27)
 (-29,3,29,27)
 (-28,3,28,27)
 (-27,3,27,27)
 (-26,3,26,27)
 (-25,3,25,27)
 (-24,-18,27,27)
 (-24,3,24,27)
 (-23,3,23,27)
 (-22,3,22,27)
 (-21,3,21,27)
 (-20,3,20,27)
 (-19,3,19,27)
 (-18,-10,19,27)
 (-18,3,18,27)
 (-17,3,17,27)
 (-16,3,16,27)
 (-15,3,15,27)
 (-14,3,14,27)
 (-13,3,13,27)
 (-12,3,12,27)
 (-11,3,11,27)
 (-10,3,10,27)
 (-9,3,9,27)
 (-8,3,8,27)
 (-7,3,7,27)
 (-6,3,6,27)
 (-5,-4,6,27)
 (-5,3,5,27)
 (-4,3,4,27)
 (-3,3,3,27)
 (-2,2,3,27)
 (-1,1,3,27)
 (0,0,3,27)
 (-59,31,56,28)
 (-17,13,14,28)
 (0,1,3,28)
 (-20,13,18,29)
 (-3,-2,4,29)
 (1,1,3,29)
 (-6,5,5,34)
 (-4,-3,5,34)
 (-1,2,3,34)
 (-13,-8,14,35)
 (0,2,3,35)
 (-75,40,71,36)
 (-3,-1,4,36)
 (1,2,3,36)
 (-56,37,50,37)
 (-3,0,4,37)
 (-27,16,25,38)
 (-3,1,4,38)
 (-52,20,51,43)
 (-13,8,12,43)
 (-7,-7,9,43)
 (2,2,3,43)
 (-7,-5,8,44)
 (-3,2,4,45)
 (-29,19,26,46)
 (-2,3,3,46)
 (-50,-50,63,47)
 (-30,-14,31,47)
 (-8,6,7,47)
 (-26,-23,31,48)
 (-2,-2,4,48)
 (-4,-2,5,53)
 (-1,3,3,53)
 (-18,-15,21,54)
 (-11,-7,12,54)
 (0,3,3,54)
 (-23,-23,29,55)
 (-9,-6,10,55)
 (-2,-1,4,55)
 (1,3,3,55)
 (-47,31,42,56)
 (-21,-11,22,56)
 (-2,0,4,56)
 (-38,25,34,57)
 (-2,1,4,57)
 (-4,-1,5,60)
 (-4,0,5,61)
 (-43,22,41,62)
 (-34,27,27,62)
 (-4,1,5,62)
 (-1,-1,4,62)
 (2,3,3,62)
 (-63,-37,67,63)
 (-58,-38,63,63)
 (-6,-4,7,63)
 (-1,0,4,63)
 (-100,4,100,64)
 (-99,4,99,64)
 (-98,4,98,64)
 (-97,4,97,64)
 (-96,4,96,64)
 (-95,4,95,64)
 (-94,4,94,64)
 (-93,4,93,64)
 (-92,4,92,64)
 (-91,4,91,64)
 (-90,4,90,64)
 (-89,4,89,64)
 (-88,4,88,64)
 (-87,4,87,64)
 (-86,4,86,64)
 (-85,4,85,64)
 (-84,4,84,64)
 (-83,4,83,64)
 (-82,4,82,64)
 (-81,4,81,64)
 (-80,-34,82,64)
 (-80,4,80,64)
 (-79,4,79,64)
 (-78,4,78,64)
 (-77,4,77,64)
 (-76,4,76,64)
 (-75,4,75,64)
 (-74,4,74,64)
 (-73,4,73,64)
 (-72,4,72,64)
 (-71,4,71,64)
 (-70,4,70,64)
 (-69,4,69,64)
 (-68,4,68,64)
 (-68,30,66,64)
 (-67,4,67,64)
 (-66,4,66,64)
 (-65,4,65,64)
 (-64,4,64,64)
 (-63,4,63,64)
 (-62,4,62,64)
 (-61,4,61,64)
 (-60,4,60,64)
 (-59,4,59,64)
 (-58,4,58,64)
 (-57,4,57,64)
 (-56,4,56,64)
 (-55,4,55,64)
 (-54,4,54,64)
 (-53,4,53,64)
 (-52,4,52,64)
 (-51,4,51,64)
 (-50,4,50,64)
 (-49,4,49,64)
 (-48,4,48,64)
 (-48,36,40,64)
 (-47,4,47,64)
 (-46,4,46,64)
 (-45,4,45,64)
 (-44,4,44,64)
 (-43,4,43,64)
 (-42,4,42,64)
 (-41,4,41,64)
 (-40,4,40,64)
 (-39,4,39,64)
 (-38,4,38,64)
 (-37,4,37,64)
 (-36,4,36,64)
 (-35,4,35,64)
 (-34,4,34,64)
 (-33,4,33,64)
 (-32,-24,36,64)
 (-32,4,32,64)
 (-32,18,30,64)
 (-31,4,31,64)
 (-30,4,30,64)
 (-29,4,29,64)
 (-28,4,28,64)
 (-27,4,27,64)
 (-26,4,26,64)
 (-25,4,25,64)
 (-24,4,24,64)
 (-23,4,23,64)
 (-22,-17,25,64)
 (-22,4,22,64)
 (-21,4,21,64)
 (-20,4,20,64)
 (-19,4,19,64)
 (-18,4,18,64)
 (-17,4,17,64)
 (-16,4,16,64)
 (-15,4,15,64)
 (-14,4,14,64)
 (-13,4,13,64)
 (-12,4,12,64)
 (-11,4,11,64)
 (-10,4,10,64)
 (-9,4,9,64)
 (-8,4,8,64)
 (-7,4,7,64)
 (-6,4,6,64)
 (-5,-3,6,64)
 (-5,4,5,64)
 (-4,4,4,64)
 (-3,3,4,64)
 (-2,2,4,64)
 (-1,1,4,64)
 (0,0,4,64)
 (0,1,4,65)
 (1,1,4,66)
 (-22,-19,26,69)
 (-4,2,5,69)
 (-64,23,63,70)
 (-21,11,20,70)
 (-33,-22,36,71)
 (-24,12,23,71)
 (-20,-16,23,71)
 (-3,-3,5,71)
 (-1,2,4,71)
 (-27,-13,28,72)
 (-10,7,9,72)
 (0,2,4,72)
 (-47,29,43,73)
 (-24,-12,25,73)
 (1,2,4,73)
 (-55,26,53,78)
 (-66,-49,74,79)
 (-33,-19,35,79)
 (-6,-6,8,80)
 (2,2,4,80)
 (-18,10,17,81)
 (-15,12,12,81)
 (3,3,3,81)
 (-11,-11,14,82)
 (-36,-32,43,83)
 (-29,22,24,83)
 (-23,-15,25,83)
 (-5,-2,6,83)
 (-2,3,4,83)
 (-16,-9,17,88)
 (-4,-4,6,88)
 (-4,3,5,88)
 (-7,6,6,89)
 (-100,31,99,90)
 (-73,-32,75,90)
 (-51,-35,56,90)
 (-48,19,47,90)
 (-27,13,26,90)
 (-9,-8,11,90)
 (-5,-1,6,90)
 (-3,-2,5,90)
 (-1,3,4,90)
 (-5,0,6,91)
 (0,3,4,91)
 (-8,-5,9,92)
 (-5,1,6,92)
 (1,3,4,92)
 (-5,-5,7,93)
 (-22,14,20,96)
 (-22,17,18,97)
 (-3,-1,5,97)
 (-15,9,14,98)
 (-3,0,5,98)
 (-37,16,36,99)
 (-5,2,6,99)
 (-3,1,5,99)
 (2,3,4,99)
 (-6,-3,7,100)
```

Comment: Did you render $x^2+t^3+[z^3=k^3$?  $k$ is not cubed in the q.

Comment: @ Oscar Lanzi  Thanks for pointing out the oversight.

Answer (score 0):

This is the low-tech approach I took for this question. Note the optional output file in lines 140 and 220. The user may copy/paste or import the data into a spreadsheet for sorting as I did for the other answer.

```
 100 print "Enter limit";
 110 input l1
 120 print time$
 130 print
 140 rem   open "outfile.txt" for output as #1
 150 for n1 = -l1 to l1
 160     for n2 = n1 to l1
 170        for n3 = n2 to l1
 180            t0 = n1^3+n2^3+n3^3
 190            for t9 = 1 to l1
 200                if t0 = t9
 210                   print "    " n1 n2 n3 t9 "."
 220                   rem  print #1, n1 n2 n3 t9 "."
 230               endif
 240             next t9
 250         next n3
 260     next n2
 270         rem The following IF/ELSE skips zero
 280         rem     for the next iteration of n1
 290         if n1 = -1
 300            n1 = 1
 310            goto 160
 320         endif
 330 next n1
 340 print time$
```