# Show that if $n \equiv 4\pmod 9$, then $n$ cannot be written as the sum of three cubes.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is a repeat of a question asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1245997/if-n-equiv-4-pmod-9-then-n-cannot-be-written-as-sum-of-three-cubes).

> Show that if $n \equiv 4 (\mod 9)$, then $n$ cannot be written as the
>   sum of three  cubes.

Solution: Any integer has *least residue* as either $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 (\mod 9)$

Now, $$0^3\equiv0 \pmod 9\\
1^3\equiv1 \pmod 9\\
2^3\equiv8 \pmod 9\\
3^3\equiv0 \pmod 9\\
4^3\equiv 1\pmod 9\\
5^3\equiv 8\pmod 9\\
6^3\equiv 0\pmod 9\\
7^3\equiv 1\pmod 9\\
8^3\equiv 8\pmod 9$$.

So,any integer cube is congruent to either $0,1 \text{or} 8 \pmod 9$

It is not possible to produce $4$ with the combination of $0,1,8$.

Closest we can get is $1+1+1=3$ or $0+0+8=8$.

My question (1) is this method correct?

Question (2) is: Why the answer to the linked question says that $m^3 \equiv 0, \pm1 \pmod9$?  How the user got "$-1$" and why "$8$" is missing?

Comment: $8+1\equiv 0$ mod 9. Therefore you can identify 8 and $-1$ when you work modulo 9. And your proof is correct.

Comment: oh, thanx @Nitrogen  very good tip, if $a\equiv b (\mod m)$ then $a+c\equiv b+c (\mod m)$, in our case since $9\equiv 0 (\mod 9)$ then $9-1\equiv 0-1 (\mod 9)$

Comment: Note that we can get $0+8+8 \equiv 7 \bmod 9$ and $8+8+8 \equiv 6 \bmod 9$. So you can probably see that $a\equiv \{4,5\} \bmod 9$ are the cases where this test on $a$ will rule out the possibility that $a$ can be the sum of three cubes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your method is correct according to the question .

Regarding the second part of your question,
You fetched 
$n'\equiv0(mod9)$

$n'\equiv1(mod9)$

$n'\equiv8(mod9)$

$\forall n'\in\mathbb Z $and n' is the sum of 3 cubes

Now you see
The actual definition of congruences  is

*If* $ m\equiv n(mod  a)$
$Then ,$
$m=a.q_1+r$

And $b=a.q_2+r$

Where $ a,q_1,q_2,r\in \mathbb Z$
Or in other words two numbers are said to be congruent *modulo* a ***iff*** they  leave same remaiders when divided by a

Now you see we say
If $m\equiv n(mod a)$,

Then $m\equiv n\pm k.a(mod a)$

***PROOF:***

**Given:**$m\equiv n(mod a)$

**To show:**$m\equiv n\pm k.a(mod a)$

**proof:**

If $m\equiv n(mod a)$.
Then m and n leaves same remainder with a.
Now,

$n=a.q_2+r$.

$\Rightarrow n\pm k.a=a.q_2+r\pm k.a$

$\Rightarrow n\pm k.a=a(q_2\pm k.a)+r$ where $k\in \mathbb Z$

Now ,
Since $q_2,k\in \mathbb Z$

And $q_2 \pm k.a\in \mathbb Z$
So we see now $n \pm a $ leaves same remainder as m and n
So we can say,

$m\equiv n\pm k.a (mod a)$

```
           -×-×-×-×-×-×-×-×-×-×-
```

Using this theorem as we prove what you have asked

You found

$n'\equiv 8(mod9)$

Therefore $n'\equiv 8-9(mod 9)$

So we get $n'\equiv -1(mod 9)$

So writing 8(mod 9) and -1(mod 9) is all the same.

So you are done!!

Answer (score 0):

HINT.- You have $8\equiv-1\pmod9$. Besides the same property goes for $n\equiv5\pmod9$, I mean

**If $n\equiv5\pmod9$ then $n$ cannot be written as the sum of three cubes.**

The proof is equal to the same as you have made for $n\equiv4\pmod9$